# Gulp Sass v4 not creating css file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm using gulp version 4 in my project and I want to compile my scss file to css file. But gulp not creating any css file.

**My gulpfile.js**

```
// Initialize modules
// Importing specific gulp API functions lets us write them below as series() instead of gulp.series()
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
// Importing all the Gulp-related packages we want to use
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var replace = require('gulp-replace');


// File paths
const files = { 
    scssPath: './assets/scss/**/*.scss',
    jsPath: './assets/js/**/*.js'
}

// Sass task: compiles the style.scss file into style.css
function scssTask(cb){    
    return src(files.scssPath)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // initialize sourcemaps first
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "expanded" }).on('error',sass.logError)) // compile SCSS to CSS
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ])) // PostCSS plugins
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // write sourcemaps file in current directory
        .pipe(dest('./dist'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
     // put final CSS in dist folder
}

// JS task: concatenates and uglifies JS files to script.js
function jsTask(){
    return src([
        files.jsPath
        //,'!' + 'includes/js/jquery.min.js', // to exclude any specific files
        ])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(dest('./dist')
    );
}

// Cachebust
var cbString = new Date().getTime();
function cacheBustTask(){
    return src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(replace(/cb=\d+/g, 'cb=' + cbString))
        .pipe(dest('.'));
}

// Watch task: watch SCSS and JS files for changes
// If any change, run scss and js tasks simultaneously
function watchTask(){
    watch([files.scssPath, files.jsPath], 
        parallel(scssTask, jsTask));    
}

// Export the default Gulp task so it can be run
// Runs the scss and js tasks simultaneously
// then runs cacheBust, then watch task
exports.default = series(
    parallel(scssTask, jsTask), 
    cacheBustTask,
    watchTask
);
```

**My Project Hiererchy**

```
myProject
     |_ assets
     |    |_ css
     |    |_ scss
     |    |_ js
     |_ index.html
     |_ node_modules
     |_ gulpfile.js
     |_ package.json
```

**and when running Gulp**

```
[14:27:33] Using gulpfile F:\blog-project\infonites\gulpfile.js
[14:27:33] Starting 'default'...
[14:27:33] Starting 'scssTask'...
[14:27:33] Starting 'jsTask'...
[14:27:33] Finished 'scssTask' after 64 ms
[14:27:37] Finished 'jsTask' after 4.36 s
[14:27:37] Starting 'cacheBustTask'...
[14:27:37] Finished 'cacheBustTask' after 7.71 ms
[14:27:37] Starting 'watchTask'...
```

**And after running gulp my project hierarchy**

```
myProject
     |_ assets
     |    |_ css
     |    |_ scss
     |    |_ js
     |_ index.html
     |_ dist
     |    |_ all.js
     |_ node_modules
     |_ gulpfile.js
     |_ package.json
```

This is my final output after running gulp task. I don't understand why gulp running js task but not css task.

Comment: Have a look at the last lines in your `scssTask`. You misplaced some brackets in `.pipe(dest('./dist')` and further.

Comment: @TheDancingCode Thank you..I fixed it, But css file still not created

Comment: @TheDancingCode I have edited my gulpfile.js

Comment: I reproduced your folder structure and am able to produce a css file. Can you show the contents of one of your `scss` files?

Comment: @TheDancingCode Yeah Sure...

`@import "_variables";
@import "_reset";

body {
    background: red;
    color: #ddd;
}`

Comment: What's your gulp version, node version and os? Can't seem to reproduce the bug.

Comment: One more thing I can think of: if the scss file you want to compile has a name starting with an underscore as well, it won't be compiled and moved to `dist`.